# I appreciate if you can tell if your platform [agora.io] can support this use case

Tags: agora.io

Below is a use case of our business - I appreciate if you can tell if the [agora.io] platform can support this use case and how i.e., what are my options, which APIs and how the billing will be calculated:

1. The lecturer is at one location and students are in a remote location. all have tablets
2. Lecturer open virtual room for a lesson and invites students to join
3. The lecturer can see, control and mute the students
4. At any moment the lecturer starts a “video session” in which students start to videoing from their tablet’s camera. the video should include also audio.
5. Videos from students’ tablet should be live-streamed with no delay to the lecturer (the lecturer can select between all the broadcasted videos and watch them and listen to the audio)
6. At any time, the lecturer can end the video session. the videos of each student must be ready immediately at the server to replay and watch
7. The lecturer can start multiple video sessions in one lesson
8. The lecturer can end lesson

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't Agora support

Answer (score 0):

Agora can totally support all these requirement. Agora video call guarantees to provide sub-second latency video communication globally. You can check this Agora Quick Start guide to understand how to use Agora video SDK: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/start_call_android?platform=Android. Regarding the billing, you can check this documents: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/billing_rtc?platform=All%20Platforms.

Now for each of your use case:

2 & 4 & 5. You will need to use the RTC SDK to start a vide call and use RTM SDK's invitation feature to send call invatation: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/rtm_invite_android?platform=Android.

3. You can use the RTM SDK to send a signal from teacher to student to control their video behavior. RTM SDK quick start: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/messaging_android?platform=Android.
4. You need to use the Agora Cloud Recording API to save the video in a cloud storage like Amazon S3. https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/product_cloud_recording?platform=Linux
5. You can join multiple channels using RTC SDK. https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/multiple_channel_android?platform=Android
6. Call leaveChannel() to end the session. https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_rtc_engine.html#a2929e4a46d5342b68d0deb552c29d597

Hope this answers your question. You can also join our Slack group to get the support: https://join.slack.com/t/agoraiodev/shared_invite/zt-e7ln476c-pfWWYMs40Y7GMPz2i26pwA